# "Manufacturing sector added 1,300 jobs in the region", is the sentence common and natural?

Tags: word-usage

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/manufacturing-industry)

> Manufacturing industry added 1,300 jobs in the region

sometimes, "manufacturing industry" and "manufacturing sector" are the same thing.

Is the sentence common and natural?

> Manufacturing sector added 1,300 jobs in the region

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the sentence as given lacks a definite article which is needed. That is, it should read:

> **The** manufacturing sector added 1,300 jobs in the region.

As for "sector" vs" industry" I wouls tend to favor"sector" myself, and my **impression** is that i have read "sector" in news stories of this kind more often. Also [theis Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=manufacturing+sector+added%2Cmanufacturing+industry+added+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmanufacturing%20sector%20added%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmanufacturing%20industry%20added%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmanufacturing%20sector%20added%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmanufacturing%20industry%20added%3B%2Cc0) shows "sector" to be used in this constructions significantly more often (in the Ngrams corpus) since about 1960. As always, some care s due in using Ngrams results, they can be deceptive.

But I am sure that either "industry" or "sector is perfectly grammatical and natural in thus use.

Comment: The Cambridge dictionary link has no article in front of “Manufacturing industry”. I personally would use a definite article there (and in front of manufacturing sector), but I wonder if it is a mistake in their corpus or if it’s possible to drop the article with industry in some circumstances. For example, https://www.nist.gov/el/applied-economics-office/manufacturing/manufacturing-industry-statistics I think it might just be when used as an attributive though.

Comment: @ColleenV
I don't think in the construction above, the article should be omitted. In a headline or title, sure, or in a phrase such as "another manufacturing industry".  Note that the text you link to never uses it without an article in prose.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find a good example, which somewhat supports that the example sentence in the dictionary isn't a great choice. I may even be a headline instead of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I would  say more naturally sounds: **Manufacturing industry created jobs in the region** than 'added jobs'. Sector sounds more like a specific ´branch´ of industry, so industry and sector are 'almost synonyms', just depending on the whole context.

Answer (score 0):

A *sector* in this context is a division of the country's economic activity https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sector
, so *the manufacturing sector* could be a synonym for manufacturing industry.